# React interract with dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

How can I 'talk' with dom elements with react?

For example - I need to bind some actions with some js lib

Both approaches returns `undefined` for some reason

```
componentDidMount() {

    const element1 = document.querySelector('.home-container')
    const element2 = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);

     // returns undefined, undefined
    console.log(element1.length, element2.length); 

}

render() {

    return (
        <div className="home-container">
            ...
        </div>
    )
}
```

But `console.log(element1)` returns html from render itself though

How can I work with them?
And what correct lifecycle method for this?

Comment: Well, `querySelector` returns either first element matching the selector or null. Why do you expect it to have `length` property. Same for `findDOMNode`.

Comment: Yep, you're right. I mean querySelectorAll. Anyway, ref - is rescue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use ["refs"](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html):

```
<div ref={e => {this.div = el}} ...>...</div>
```

Once your component has rendered, with the above, its `div` property (you can use any name you want) will refer to the `div` element that was rendered.

Here's an example largely copied from the link above that focuses a text input when it's rendered:

```js
class AutoFocusTextInput extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.textInput.focus();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <input type="text"
        ref={(input) => { this.textInput = input; }} />
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <AutoFocusTextInput />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```